# java process cannot be started

Tags: java, crash, jvm

Background: Since the past few days, my linux development machine Java services one by one by the system kill, I looked at the system logs are OOM caused. Now I can't start the java process if I set the initial heap too large.

I can't see with the usual troubleshooting means, the development machine is a virtual machine (I don't think I can exclude the problem of the physical machine where the virtual machine is located, my colleague's machine and I applied at the same time, also have this problem), the total memory is about 6G, buff/cache + free total of about 5G. Thank you all for your help.

The crash logs at startup are in the attachment, and the system information and jdk information are in there.

[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/wangzzleo/dbbf27c9d350f6f7eae1f56564915bcd)

Start-up log:

```
[~ jdk1.8.0_281]$java -Xms1000m  -version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000a5400000, 699400192, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 699400192 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid7617.log
```

Memory usage is as follows:

```
[~ jdk1.8.0_281]$free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5.7G        502M        213M        4.6G        5.0G        328M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

The io situation is as follows:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.03     2.77    0.84    2.80    48.95    97.58    80.57     0.05   22.14   65.48    9.22   0.55   0.20
scd0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.01     0.00    66.96     0.00    0.34    0.34    0.00   0.24   0.00
```

Comment: According to `free` you have `213M ` free memory. What do you expected to happend when you gave java `-Xms1000m`?

Comment: I suppose, the “available” column does already consider the caches that could be released when needed. 328M still is significantly less than 1000m and a JVM also needs memory for other things besides the heap.

Comment: I don't really understand the principle of memory allocation, the buff/cache part of the memory can be used when needed, right? Besides, the OS can use swap memory when memory is low, right?

Comment: It says that you have 0 swap. You probably didn't setup swap partition.

Comment: I tried restarting the VM and everything was solved. The swap is still 0 though, and it looks like it just deferred the crash.   
```total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5.7G        3.3G        229M        805M        2.2G        1.3G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Comment: Shared is `805M` now, vs. `4.6G` last time.

Comment: …and the “available” column looks different too